# Bash redirect doesn't work in Cron

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to redirect STDOUT and STDERR with `&>>` in my cron job, but I'm not seeing anything in the log file. The file is being created on the first run, but no OUT or ERR.

When I run a command with the `&>>` redirect directly, it works as expected.

I can successfully redirect output with `... >> /tmp/log 2>&1`, but according to [this GNU page (3.6.5)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), these two approaches are equivalent, so I'm not sure why the first approach isn't working.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Code sample:

```bash
#
# test.bash
#
echo "OUT"
ecko "ERR"
```

```
#
# crontab
#
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/test.bash &>> /tmp/test_log_1      # NOT WORKING
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/test.bash >> /tmp/test_log_2 2>&1  # WORKING
```

```bash
#
# using redirect directly works as expected
#
$ /bin/bash /root/test.bash &>> /tmp/test_log_3
$ /bin/bash /root/test.bash &>> /tmp/test_log_3
$ cat /tmp/test_log_3
OUT
/root/test.bash: line 2: ecko: command not found
OUT
/root/test.bash: line 2: ecko: command not found
```

System details:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Bash 5.0.17
- Cron 3.0pl1-136ubuntu1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cron interprets job entries using `/bin/sh` by default, which doesn't support the `&>>` redirection syntax.

If you want the job to be run in a different shell, you can set the `SHELL` variable inside your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/test.bash &>> /tmp/test_log_1
```

Please refer to `man 5 crontab` for details.